# Automatic push notification without server part

Tags: android, push-notification

Is there a way to organize automatic notification pushes without server part for android?

I have a service on pc (not on phone), that periodically add data to google doc or google disc.
So on every new info i want to push notification.

For me it's seems like not possible, but may be not?

Comment: Use FCM...........

Comment: Imagine, I have a file on pc, I add new string to this file and want automatically push notification with that string to subscribed phones.

FCM probably cannot detect new string like this

Comment: inside your service (PC) you need to call web API of FCM to send a push notification to particular device ID

Comment: Thanks, will try it

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a local notification in your service class. So once you have updated the data you can just build a new notification like this.

```
    private void sendUpdateNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingItent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setTicker(msg)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("My App")
                    .setContentText(msg);
    notificationManager.notify(notifyID, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: Ahhh ok. I would take a look at FCM. Take a look here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: It works fine with firebase and another service (one signal), but only manually pushing notification.